# How to manually create id value using Razor C# syntax for html textbox element?

Tags: c#, html, razor

For example, I have this textbox

```
 <input id="@item.Id" type="number" value="@item.TotalAmount" />
```

and when rendered out, it becomes

```
<input id="1048" type="number" value="3.60" />
```

How do I add a letter to the id to make the rendered out textbox to become?

```
<input id="T1048" type="number" value="3.60" />
```

I tried below but it doesn't work

```
<input id="T@item.Id" type="number" value="@item.TotalAmount" />
```

Comment: try with `id='T@(item.id)'` or you can also use `String.Format("T{0}", @item.id)` with Razor. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this it will resolve your issue

```
<input id="item_@(item.Id)" type="number" value="@item.TotalAmount" />
```

or you can also use String.Format in it like

```
<input id="@String.Format("item_{0}", item.Id)">
```